# Strategies for implementing a user specific - custom content EntryPoint in GWT

Tags: gwt, web-applications, dashboard, gwt-rpc

We have developed a dashboard in GWT that contains some custom widgets for displaying customer's data in various graphical forms. We now want to move to a more custom / user specific approach where each customer who logs into the dashboard can see a different perspective of the dashboard. Some widgets will be available for some users, for some others not and with different initialization parameters.

We are trying to find an efficient strategy to do this. A potential solution would be to have the client side request all this information during EntryPoint loading and then use that incoming configuration to build itself and make further requests for the data. A more efficient solution would also allow downloading to the browser only those widgets relevant to the user.

Does GWT have any design pattern for this scenario? If not, what would a good high level solution be for this case?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is atleast one mechanism that can be useful to achieve your requirements

- [Code Splitting](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html) :- The idea is to split the particular section of code and download it in independent async call. Using this approach you can reduce the size of primary javascript file making initial page load faster. This approach allow GWT to skip inclusion of all those widgets which have references only inside `GWT.runAsync()` method in primary js file. Such widgets and code gets downloaded when application runs that code in independent call. you can use this approach and avoid download of additional dashboard charts based on some conditions like user type and so. Here is sample code from [GWT reference website](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html)

  ```
  public class Hello implements EntryPoint {

     public void onModuleLoad() {

         Button b = new Button("Click me", new ClickHandler() {
             public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                 GWT.runAsync(new RunAsyncCallback() {

                     public void onFailure(Throwable caught) {
                         Window.alert("Code download failed");
                     }

                     public void onSuccess() {
                         Window.alert("Hello, AJAX");
                     }
                 });
             }
         });
         RootPanel.get().add(b);
     }
  }
  ```

Comment: Thank you Ajax! We should use this future, especially if we have a large number of widgets. I was also wondering if there is a design pattern for the case I described, where you can have different views for different users. How to set it up. Code splitting is more of an optimisation pattern as of my understanding.